# Removing implication from the compound proposition

Tags: logic

Say I have the following 
$(a \land b) \rightarrow (b \lor a)$ and am asked to remove the implication. Does this mean I remove $\rightarrow$ and create a new compound proposition such that if will have the same truth table, or does this mean I create a new compound proposition that has a different truth table, all with the same propositions of course? In essence, does removing an implication remove its truth values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implications can be written as compound statements.

$$P\Rightarrow Q$$

is logically equivalent to

$$\neg P\vee Q$$

For yours, apply the above change to your statement where instead of $P$ you have $a\wedge b$ and instead of $Q$ you have $b\vee a$

Comment: I see, since I got the same truth table I think it's safe to assume "removing the implication" means remove the logical operation and figure out a way to yield the same truth table. Considering how many possible compound propositions one can make, this can't be the only way to remove it correct? Is this the most direct way?

Comment: Generally speaking, this is how implications are *defined* in most textbooks.  In that sense, I would consider it the most direct way, yes.